# Promotion: Boston Security Meetup; BSides Delaware

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A good crowd of folks were at the last one I attended. I'd like to promote at the October and November meetups and the Delaware BSides.

Boston: October 20th
Boston: November 10th (speaking)
Delware BSides: November 11th-12th

http://www.meetup.com/boston-security-meetup/

http://www.securitybsides.com/w/page/28563447/BSidesDelaware

Comment: Could you ballpark the numbers for attendees?

Comment: Boston: 30-50, probably a fair amount of overlap between the two dates.
Delaware: Several hundred; will try to confirm a number with organizers.